# I need to replace values in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm developing a windows form application that contacts with SQL server. I have the following question how can I replace that values in that columns:

```
INSERT INTO SimpleTest(ID,Name,Country,Number,Gender) Values('4','Test','TestCountry','09432432','male')
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use UPDATE instead of INSERT.

Comment: What does this have to do with `c#` and `winforms`? You've made a statement, showed an `INSERT` statement, and not asked a question. What does this have to do with `REPLACE()`?

Comment: Perhaps you mean you want to replace the `VALUES` clause? With what, a `SELECT`? Take the time to explain your requirement, and don't forget, when posting a *question* it's important to ask one (a question).

Comment: Maybe he is using windows forms as technology, who knows. But as said you can use UPDATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use UPDATE instead of Insert: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

Comment: Please! No w3fools link, that is awful!

Comment: can I Update the values withouth Where condition ?

Comment: Yes but then you will update ALL rows in the table :)

Comment: @OcasoProtal why not? Usually W3School examples are very simple and it allow you  o play around.

Comment: They are simple, that is right. But w3schools tend to have errors (at least the HTML sections). And if an exact RDBMS is given, it is better to link to that: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 This might be more complex at first, but hopefully the OP will learn a lot more from these

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE SimpleTest SET name = 'Test'
    , country= 'TestCountry'
    , Number='09432432'
    , Gender= 'Male'
    WHERE ID='4'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your database values using the UPDATE method instead of INSERT. 
To do this, say your data:

```
UPDATE YourTableName 
SET Name = 'Test', 'and so on the table fields'
WHERE ID = 'id';
```

That's it!